# API for manipulating audio output in windows 8

Tags: audio, windows-8

I want to manipulate audio output data, for all the different running applications, before it is sent to the speakers.
Turn the volume up or down, filter the audio, things like that.

How can I gain access to the audio output in real time?

Is there a way to not depend on the audio driver interface?

Thanks! :)

Comment: Do you mean for Windows Store/WinRT apps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows Store apps allow you to use [WASAPI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/dd371455%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). In WASAPI, there is a concept of "audio sessions", of which there is one for every stream of audio being sent to the soundcard. You can [enumerate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/dd368281%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) the audio sessions which give you access to [IAudioSessionControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/dd368246%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). However, this doesn't let you manipulate the audio, which as far as I know WASAPI simply doesn't allow. The best you can hope for is to get hold of [ISimpleAudioVolume](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd316531%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for each session, but last time I tried that, I found that you couldn't get hold of the session GUIDs you needed to adjust the volume for other processes. You may be able to get hold of the [audio endpoints](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd370793%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and adjust the master volume for the soundcard.

In short, WASAPI is the most powerful audio API for Windows Store apps but unfortunately I don't think it will let you do very much of what you are asking here.